# Throw new Exception to logger.error

Tags: java, exception, logging

Id like to add this exception to the logger:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("ex msg");
```

But when I try it like this, I get error on "throw ex;"

```
Exception ex= new IllegalArgumentException("ex msg");
log.error("msg",ex);
throw ex;
```

Any idea how to solve this? 
Thanks

Comment: Why did you throw ex? Just omit that

Comment: ` i get error` - _which_ error?

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the specific type for `ex`, i.e. `IllegalArgumentException ex` or at least `RuntimeException ex` since `Exception` is a checked exception and if there is no `throws Exception` in the method signature the compiler will complain.

Bad:

```
public void myMethod() {
  throw new Exception(); //this needs to be declared
}
```

Good:

```
public void myMethod() throws Exception {
  throw new Exception(); 
}

public void myMethod() {
  throw new RuntimeException(); //those don't have to be declared
}
```

Your code is similar to the bad example since for the compiler `thow ex` looks like `throw new Exception()` (not exactly but you should get the point).

Answer (score 1):

```
Exception ex= new IllegalArgumentException("ex msg");
```

this makex `ex` an `Exception` and you can't `throw Exception` without declaring it in method signature, so change below sentence by:

```
IllegalArgumentException ex= new IllegalArgumentException("ex msg");
```

Or add `throw Exception` in you method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Your abstraction is incorrect for the method signature.

```
Exception ex = ... // The left side is a checked exception
...
throw ex; // Mr. Compiler, I want to throw a checked exception!
```

You are telling the compiler you want to throw a checked `Exception` but the method doesn't declare it.  It's good practice to use the least amount of abstraction possible on the left side of the assignment, but in this case you went too far :)  You need `RuntimeException` instead of `Exception`.

```
// RuntimeException is unchecked.  No need to declare it.
RuntimeException ex = new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
```

Instead of

```
// Exception is checked and needs to be declared
Exception ex = new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code should work. Logger should internally take the throwing exceptions and should print it. You do not have to include it inside a logger (info/debug/error). The below code is more than enough. It will not print in the error console (system console) if the logger is configured properly.

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("ex msg");
```

And still it does not work, try this:

```
logger.error("Some exception happened : ", throw new IllegalArgumentException("ex msg"));
```

Note the comma to separate the string and exception